# Ender 5 Pro bent/curved print on base

Tags: creality-ender-5

[image]Ender 5 Pro prints are very uneven on base of the model.

In this example I printed an SD card dummy but it is not even flat.

Having a glass bed it is super strange to see this kind of behaviour.

Here are parameters in Cura.

```
M92 X80.00 Y80.00 Z800.00 E94.5 ;Setup step mm
M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00 ;Setup machine max acceleration
M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E50.00 ;Setup machine max feedrate
M204 P500.00 R1000.00 T500.00 ;Setup Print/Retract/Travel acceleration
M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E5.00 ;Setup Jerk
```

Thanks in advance, I tried quite a few calibrations but nothing helped so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! This is a classic example of not enough adhesion. Tune bed temperature, use a brim or add an adhesive layer like glue stick or hair spray or a dedicated print adhesion spray.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Oscar - indeed, I used a glue stick and the issue disappeared. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of not enough adhesion. Tune bed temperature (usually hotter), use a brim or add an adhesive layer like glue stick or hair spray or a dedicated print adhesion spray.

The question "[Warping of bottom of print](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)" has [an accepted answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5237) that explains in detail how and why this occurs.

Comment: This. However most often ppl try to solve it by smashing tighter against the build platform, which causes elephant foot and other nasty issues. In my experience hotter bed temp and brim are the right fixes, and brim works even with a brim gap of 0.25-0.3 mm which avoids marring of the part.

Comment: Cheers, will also try to increase the bed temperature. Currently set to 50 degrees celsius