# Intermittent lifting (Creality CR-6SE + glass bed + stock PLA) issues

Tags: pla, creality-ender-6

- Creality CR-6 SE 1.0.2
- Creality Slicer 4.2.1
- stock PLA roll
- Slicer settings: Default (generic PLA) 0.2

Having intermittent issues where prints (usually edge) would "lift".
I replaced the bed, and the filament, and I don't see this issue anymore, but..
I'm a new student of 3D printing, I want to understand why issues happen, and not just how to patch/workaround them.

[image: Lifting]

Comment: This is a classic example of not enough adhesion. Adding brim, more temperature in the bed and using an adhesive like glue stick, hair spray or a dedicated print adhesion spray solved the issue. See e.g. [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14894/ender-5-pro-bent-curved-print-on-base) which is very similar.

Comment: Thanks! I postulated that it was either adhesion issue or cold bed. I may have inadvertently improved this issue by switching from glass to PEI bed, but, as always, it's good to understand why things happen and learn properly.